# I want to acess the value of this json object without using the key name

Tags: node.js, json

```
{ 
"callExpDateMap": {
        "2020-03-06:2": {
            "305.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL,
                }
               ]
              }
             }
            }
```

So this is my json object.And As you can see in "callExpDateMap",there is a date("2020-03-06:2" and then there is a value("305.0").The date("2020-03-06:2") and price("305.0") values will not be the same in every response.So If I want to access the value of "putCall" (Please remember that I can't use the key of the date and the price because it keeps changing in every response), How can I do this?...I'm using nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop over the object and get the value,

Example:

```js
let test = {
  callExpDateMap: {
    "2020-03-06:2": {
      "305.0": [
        {
          putCall: "CALL"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

let callExpDateMap = test.callExpDateMap;


for(const dateValue in callExpDateMap) {
  for(const put in callExpDateMap[dateValue]) {
    console.log(callExpDateMap[dateValue][put][0]['putCall']);
  }
  
}
```

or you could use `Object.keys` to get the value. it's simpler then the previous approach;

```js
let obj = {
  callExpDateMap: {
    "2020-03-06:2": {
      "305.0": [
        {
          putCall: "CALL"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

let callExpDateMap = obj.callExpDateMap;
let dateKey = Object.keys(callExpDateMap);
let price =  Object.keys(callExpDateMap[dateKey]);
let putCall = callExpDateMap[dateKey][price];
console.log(putCall);
```

Comment: I have add one more method by using the Object.keys. the second one is more simpler.

Comment: I tried to do that but then I get an errror for some reason.

Comment: The second method gives me this error:Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys

Comment: I think it's throwing because of missing key. but these both methods will work until you have the data in the same format .

Comment: Do you have discord...I can contact you there..Please.

Comment: The first method works but for some reason due to sync and async issues in the for loop it is causing trouble

Comment: Sorry I don't have discord. But there is nothing async in the code .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209039/discussion-between-marcose-gigu-and-sohail).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass this JSON to a function and call that function recursively with each inner object (or value of JSON key) and when value is string just print it or use in your way.

```
forEach(Object.keys(jsonobj))

    function myfunc(key){
      if((typeof jsonobj[key])==object){
        forEach(Object.keys(jsonobj[key]));
    }else{
        console.log(jsonobj[key])
      }
    }
    }
```